# Can one debug javascript on a samsung tablet's native browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, debugging, browser

I am currently working on a HTML/JS application that will be embedded in an iOS and an Android app. Because the android app is not yet finished I am testing this on the chrome browser in Android. I fixed all issues there but when I open the same web app in the native browser nothing really works as expected.

So my question is : **Is there a way to debug in a native browser on an android device?**

In chrome this was pretty easy with [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging).

(Please do not advice me to use 'log' statements for debugging because that's not what I am looking for here)

And just to spill my guts : the Samsung Tablet's native browser is the only device that's causing me a headache!

Answer (score 7):

Typing `about:debug` in the address bar of the native browser will **toggle** the 'Debug' options in the settings menu.

The 'Show JavaScript Console' option will allow you to see JavaScript errors in your webpage.

NB I believe the JavaScript Console will only be displayed if there is an error.

HTH

Nick.

Comment: This does not work for me.  It either tries to do a web search, (i see the auto-complete suggesting an https://www.google.com/search? URL) or else it wants to auto-complete to chrome://debug, which brings up "This web page is not available. The webpage at chrome://debug/ might be temporarily down..." HUH?!!!

Comment: Strangely enough, I already see "Debug" under Settings, and "Show JavaScript Console" is already checked... so I'm a bit at a loss as to how to make it actually appear.  I'm assuming there actually IS an error, as my page hangs executing some javascript code and does not produce the expected output.

Comment: What device are you on Michael? I'm on a Samsung Galaxy S4 (4.2.2) and I'm having the same problem, except I can't see Debug in the settings or Show Javascript Console. I have an S3 as well and about:debug works fine, they seem to have changed it for the S4 though, the stock browser is using Chrome's rendering engine by the looks of it or something strange is going on.

Answer (score 4):

The new **Samsung Internet** browser (I think you meant this browser with "Samsung Tablet's native browser") is now based on the Chromium browser and thus supports its remote debugging interface.

1. Enable USB debugging on your device as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app).
2. Then connect your device via USB (Oh, surprise!).
3. Visit `chrome://inspect` on your computers Google Chrome browser and you will be guided to create the connection:

   [image: Chrome inspect]
4. Then you just have to click on the devices `inspect` link and an developer tools window will pop up.

More info like why there is an **Samsung Internet** Browser at all can be found [here](https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/introducing-samsung-internet-for-developers-6c3a3be42f72).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily debug your web application with **Web Inspector Remote** ([weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/)).

Look at this [post](http://dustint.com/post/482/getting-started-with-weinre-mobile-debugging-on-windows) in order to find out how to install and use weinre.

I hope it will help you if this question is still actual.

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated your device you can go to `settings` -> `Debug` -> `'Remote Debug Enable'`
Once enabled you can debug the native browser just like you can debug chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [vorlon](http://vorlonjs.com) solution too, it has a nice web interface & very easy to install

& It's free

But if you can't see clear console errors with volron, you probably want to use @Nick's solution, sometimes complex errors prevents even vorlon or [weiner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/weinre) from catching them. So once you fix blocking these issues, probably volron will start catching them properly